# Android - Bundle savedInstanceState is null in Fragment onCreate() and onCreateView()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass arguments to a `Fragment`.

On clicking `View` of a `Fragment`, I replace my `Fragment` with another and pass data to be used into next `Fragment`.

My click action :

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("order", orders.get(position));
    OrderDetailFragment orderDetailFragment = new OrderDetailFragment();
    orderDetailFragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.order_activity_content_frame, orderDetailFragment)
            .addToBackStack("orderDetails")
            .commit();
}
```

But in my destination `Fragment`, `savedInstanceState` is coming to be `null`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    order = (Order) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("order");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_details, container, false);
    TextView date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.order_detail_date);
    date.setText((CharSequence) order.getCreatedOn());
    return rootView;
}
```

I am not able to figure out what exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`savedInstanceState` contains the data saved in `onSaveInstanceState()`, which is called before your `Activity`/`Fragment` is getting killed by the OS (to reclaim memory for example, or because of an orientation change).

Call `getArguments()` to get the `Bundle` you saved with `setArguments()`:

```
order = (Order) getArguments().getSerializable("order");
```

Also, the recommended practice to instantiate a `Fragment` with arguments is via a static `newInstance()` method, something like this:

```
public static OrderDetailFragment newInstance(Order order) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(KEY_ORDER, order);
    OrderDetailFragment fragment = new OrderDetailFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

And then you instantiate your `Fragment` like this:

```
OrderDetailFragment orderDetailFragment = OrderDetailFragment
    .newInstance(orders.get(position));
```